# Trying to normalise values in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, histogram, normalization, contrast

I will be producing those images and I want to make out of it intensity colour plot. I want to take those plots and have a 0 to 256 range with contrast that allows for describable features to emerge.

[image]

Bright regions will vary in the range of 100 to 400,000,000 and dark will always be at zero. Range goes up to 400,000,000, but neighbouring bright values will be similar. It is a cumulative sum of previous image instances that's why the upper limit is so high.

Now I would like all the bright values to rather be of shades of gray or some other colour coding. Experimenting with that single image and trying to get something which is more revealing to the human eye I get this.
[image]
That's with basic imadjust(I) and histeq(I,256).
This doesn't help much as contrast stretching just rounds down all the high values to the value of 1 while histogram equalisation makes the background gray of 0.8601 value.

Same operation but on the stock image gives results below.
[image]
That's more what I would expect from those operations. I have tried tweaking imadjust() gamma ratio as well as parameters relating to histeq() to no avail.

Basically I know I am fundamentally misunderstanding something either about how normalisation is carried out in digital image processing or something specific to do with the matlab.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your input data is not scaled right.

`imadjust()` has `[low_in high_in] — Contrast limits for input image` as input argument. The default setting is `[0 1]` which does not match your data.

Rescale your data with `I = rescale(I,0,256)` and try `imadjust` and `histeq` again.